# How to constrain a matrix by the sum of its rows columns and diagonals

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create an NxN matrix that randomly turns N number of zeros into ones.

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
while i = find(sum(board) > 1)
  board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
end
while i = find(sum(board,2) > 1)
    board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
end
while t= sum(diag(board) > 1)
    board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
end

board
```

My first three lines of code does what is intended. It randomly turns N number of "0"s into "1"s. But now I'm trying to set restrictions such that there can only be one "1" in each row, column, and diagonal. My logic is that the matrix should first make sure that no individual column can sum to be greater than one. I would like this placement to be constrained. Next I would like the matrix to make sure that no individual row can sum to be greater than one. This would be a second constraint in addition to the first. Lastly, the matrix should make sure that no diagonal can sum to be greater than one.

The goal would be an NxN matrix that has N number of "1"s with only one "1" in each column, row, and diagonal. Is my code on the right track?

Edit:

```
while (sum(board) > 1)
  board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
end
```

If I start with just the columns, this will give me an output. But how can I make it look at the sum of each individual column so it knows to keep looking for solution?

Edit 2:

```
prompt = 'Please input number of queens: ';
N = input(prompt);
board=zeros(N);
board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
while any(sum(board) > 1) || any(sum(board,2) > 1) || any(sum(spdiags(board)) > 1)
    board = zeros(N); 
    board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
end

for index = 1:numel(board)
    if board(index) == 0
        board(index) = 8;
    end
end


board

if sum(board(:)==1) == N
    disp('Solution!')
else
    disp('Failed solution!')
end
```

I added a few extra goodies. I understand why a break should probably be added (and I see why my way of doing this is inefficient now) but I only need to go up until N=8 so I decided to remove it. The only part that isn't working is my diagonals

Final edit:
I got it!

```
||any(sum(spdiags(board))>1)||any(sum(spdiags(rot90(board)))>1)
```

Thank you SO MUCH for all your help!

Comment: This looks like its a variation of the 8-queen problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), only you allow for off-center diagonals to have more than one 'queen'.  I recommend you look at algorithms used for this problem and modify them to suit your less stringent restrictions.

Comment: Yup, it definitely is the 8 queens problem. However, I'd like to try it this way if possible. The logic makes sense to me. I'm new to matlab and I'm sure my idea has many problems yet to be seen. But as long as I can get it close so that the logic is there, it's not the end of the world if I can't get it to actually work.

Comment: Alright, in that case you should start with making your sample code directly executable - it currently has some bugs unrelated to your question (e.g. those while-loops will not run).

Comment: The original code for those came from examples I saw of 'for' loops. They're not interchangeable I guess. If I switch them all back to for loops, they work but they aren't given the desired output. Any ideas for what I can try and change? My thinking is that I would like a loop to run until it detects that no sum in any direction is greater than 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you're trying to use this as a learning example, I'll not provide you with the full answer. This should be enough to help you on your way though. If you want me to elaborate more, let me know.

I've fixed the minor bugs and added a break. What's left to be done is to modify the while-condition to include row and diagonal sums. For this look up or statements (`||`). Note that this approach will become very inefficient as N increases in size so it's wise to have a break built in.

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
nIter = 1; 
while any(sum(board) > 1) 
    board = zeros(N); % Make sure to reset the board, otherwise it'll become a matrix of ones!
    board(randperm(numel(board), N))=1;
    nIter = nIter + 1; 
    % Keep track of the amount of iterations. If it becomes too much just end the loop.
    if nIter > 1000
        warning('Exceeded iteration threshold')
        break
    end
end

board
```

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. So now when I modify the while condition, would I just add an & on line 5 then add the row and diagonal condition? Essentially multiple conditions for one while loop?

Comment: Also, what did you mean by "For this look up or statements (||)"?

Comment: Or statements (denoted with `||` or `|`) allow you to have the while loop run if any one from a set of multiple conditions is satisfied. If you'd add `&&` then the conditions for rows/columns/diagonals would all have to evaluate to true, whereas `||` will make the while loop run when only one of the conditions evaluates to true.

Comment: Ah, I see! Okay, so when I add "|| any(sum(board,2) > 1) || any(sum(diag(board)) > 1)" the columns and rows work beautifully, but the diagonals do not. Is there a better function to choose for this?

Comment: Take a look at `spdiags`.

Comment: spdiags(B,d,m,n) is this the form that I can incorporate? So it would look something like | | any(sum(spdiags(board,d,N,N))) > 1?

Comment: I added my updated code to the original question. The only thing I still don't understand is the function for diagonals

Comment: Look at `sum(spdiags([1:3;4:6;7:9]))` and see how it counts the left-to-right top-to-bottom diagonals of the matrix. You'll have to flip your matrix to do the other diagonal as well.